# azure ad b2c custompolicy,givenname and surname is removed from UI form,if AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId is included as ValidationTechnicalProfile

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

After social login, I want to capture givenname, surname, and some other information from the user and then store the user in the directory and then pass these details to external API.

But the moment I include "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" in the validation profile, the givenname and surname is removed from the user form. I am not sure why does this occur as I have to include the AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId to read other custom fields

self asserted technical profile :

```
     <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-ObtainUserInfo">
      <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
        <Item Key="language.button_continue">Next</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenname"/>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"/>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId"/>           
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>   
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>            
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenname"  Required="true"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true" />            
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" ContinueOnError="false">
        <Preconditions>
             <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                 <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
             </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>objectId</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
         </ValidationTechnicalProfile>          
         <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" ContinueOnError="false">
         <Preconditions>
             <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                 <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
             </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                <Value>objectId</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
         </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="API-RegisterUserInExternalSystem" />            
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Observation: If I comment out the givenname, surname from the output claim of AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId these fields will be visible on the form.

Comment: If a claim is output via a validation technical profile, it will hide the user input field as part of the UI when simultaneously trying to output from the self asserted technical profile. That’s because B2C thinks I’m getting the claim from the VTP, no reason in asking the user.

Comment: So how do I read other fields which are part of UserReadUsingObjectId without hiding givenname and surname on the form. Shouldn't there be a flag which suggests that these fields will be an userinput rather than assuming it will be populated by validationprofile.

Comment: Simplest way is to reference the UserReadUsingObjectId TP from an orchestration step. Otherwise, the flag you mention is modelled by the use of display claims instead of output claims. Display claims are not effected by the effect I explained prior.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try with Display Claims

Answer (score 0):

**Use Case: User Journey where User will do Social Login and then User will be checked in AAD B2C and if not present then will prompt user to provide few more details and then add it to AAD B2C and then call REST API to add Users in External System.**

Here in your solution ValidationTechnical Profile of "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" where you
included GivenName, SurName etc, which is the Reason "SelfAsserted-ObtainUserInfo" technical profile considering the givenName and surName claim as Read Data but not considering as UserInputType which is the reason you are not able to see it .

Let me try to Provide you Solution how you can implement:

1. **Orchestration Step1** : Technical Profile to Login with Social.
2. **Orchestration Step2** : Technical Profile to ReadUsingAlternativeSecurityID, from here if your social account data exist in AAD B2C then you will get objectID.
3. **Orchestration Step3** : Precondition to check if ObjectID present or not (You can add more precondition if you want), if it is not present then run the step where you run the TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-ObtainUserInfo" and in the validation profile include "AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" and "API-RegisterUserInExternalSystem" without any PreRequisite in the ValidationTechnicalProfile.

Refer this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAccounts) to get the starter pack and refer UserJourney "SignUpOrSignIn".